# Entity framework 4 - Table with Identity column addition

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, edmx

I have a table defined in a SQL Server database as follows

Columns

1. `MID     Int` foreign Key
2. `MRUOMID Int` foreign Key

All columns in this table are foreign keys and referring to other entities.

I wish to add an `Identity` column to this table. If I do so and update the EDMX model from the database, I get the following error.

> problem in mapping fragments starting at 7462. You must specify mapping for all key properties.

I need an `identity` column to be added which I can refer to in my Entity model further.

Please let me know on this issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While updating, make sure you include the foreign keys too.